# Duplicate duplicate button

Tags: bug, flags

Confusing title, right?

You can flag a question as a duplicate here.

[image: 1st duplicate duplicate]

Now, click on "it should be closed for another reason".

[image: 2nd duplicate duplicate]

Why is there a duplicate duplicate button?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the iOS app. It's the same way on the desktop website.

Comment: @Doorknob Thank you for editing the question! I did not know it also affected the website version.

Comment: Duplicate duplicate is also a duplicate.

Comment: @ShadowWizard True; but nothing was done and/or declined. Also, thank you for the tongue twister. You forgot the word "duplicate" :P

Comment: Still not a reason to leave both open, if and when official response is given, it better be done in the original discussion.

Answer (score 0):

It is the "duplicate" button on the front is really a shortcut of the other "duplicate" button. Wait. What?! So here is the first pop up box when you press the flag button (mainly the computer, without the freehand stuff):[image]

Now when you press the "it should be closed for another reason" button, it should lead up to here (once again, without the freehand):[image]
It should look very similar to yours. Now click the "duplicate..." button and you should get this image (and once again without the freehand). Please notice the part I circled:
[image]
So nothing really interesting. Just a little text feature that shows you what you went through. It is correct since you first was in the flagging section then the "this question doesn't belong here because" section right? So let's assume we are back when you first press/click the flag button. Then press the duplicate button on that section (not the second one, the first one). Then look at the little text feature on top:
[image]
It's the same as the third image! How? You are probably thinking I am lying and am using the same exact image. I'm not. The "duplicate" button on the flagging section (the "it should be closed for another reason..." button should be right under it). When you press/click it, it literally skips the "it should be closed for another reason... section" as if you pressed/clicked that instead. That proves that one of the duplicate of the duplicate button is a shortcut and the other one is the "real" one. Why? I don't really know. I hope this helps you and sorry about all the images!

Comment: In other words, one of the duplicate buttons are a shortcut to the other duplicate button? Weird.

Comment: Exactly right you are.

Comment: @Oded why is this?

Comment: I have the worst freehands ever...